# didSelectRowAtIndexPath - access tapCount or similar

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, didselectrowatindexpath

I'd like to control an instance of AVAudioPlayer from a UITableView item in a didSelectRowAtIndexPath instance.

First touch of the row item triggers 'play' of the AVAudioPlayer.  Second touch of the row item triggers 'stop' of the AVAudioPlayer.

I can make the 'play' work but can't get the 'stop' to work.  Also, subsequent touches of the row item starts another thread of the audio in the background.

## What's the best way to ensure 1 tap starts the audio and a 2nd tap stops it?

Code samples - this method preps audio file and AVAudioPlayer for use:

```
- (void)makeReadyAudio {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Murderers" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error;
musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

This block will start & stop the AVAudioPlayer within a case statement in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath section:

```
case 7: {
        //touch to start audio sound playing, touch again to  stop playing
        [self makeReadyAudio];
        if ([musicPlayer isPlaying]) {
            [musicPlayer stop];
            NSLog(@"musicPlayer tested to be playing, so stop it.");
        } else {
            [musicPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"musicPlayer tested to be *not* playing, so play it.");
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
- (void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
{
    if (player.isPlaying) {
        [player stop];
    } else {
        [player start];
    }
}
```

In other words, keep the player around and see what it is doing.

Comment: if ([player isPlaying]) {
 [player stop];
 NSLog(@"player tested to be playing, so stop it.");
} else {
 [player play];
 NSLog(@"player tested to be *not* playing, so play it.");
}

Seemed plausible, no luck though.  Same behavior, the 'true' test case never seems to be run.  Repeated touches of the selected row print "player tested to be *not* playing, so play it" over and over again in the log...while playing the audio again.

Hmm.

Comment: Then show more code. Sounds like the error is somewhere else. LIke for example your AVAudioPlayer code.

Comment: code added to above problem statement...sorry supported markup tags not most intuitive @ StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `makeReadyAudio` every single time the row is tapped. You need to check if you have already done that. For example by doing something like:

```
if (musicPlayer == nil) {
    [self makeReadyAudio];
}
```

Comment: Of course. Ok next time I'm back at my development machine I'll give it a try.